# Linux iptabxes Firewall Rule

Tags: firewall

We have dedicated hosting with Godaddy and backup service. The automated backups seems to be failing since last few days. After reading further we found that TCP and ICMP inbound and outbound communication are tobe allowed to one of the IP address provided by GoDaddy.

We have the access to the server with root privileges and need to know the right command line to allow or add this rule into firewall.

Tried:
iptables -A INPUT -s IPADDRESS -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -s IPADDRESS -j ACCEPT

Saved
/sbin/service iptables save

restarted iPtables
/etc/init.d/iptables restart

No luck, how can we confirm if the same is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider adding the tcp protocol like :

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s ip@ -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Tried this:

 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s IPADDRESS --dport PORTNUMBER -j ACCEPT

but that dint work,

Comment: To make sure its the firewall, cau you disable your firewall and see if tis gonna work.  `service iptables stop`

Comment: Hey you are right, even when stopped. I cant telnet. What else could be blocking this? Any Ideas.

Comment: I have no experience with backups policy, its to risky and i'm not sure of but can you set SELinux to permissive `setenforce 0`  just for a brief test.